# Error while pdf to text conversion using textract

Tags: python, text-extraction, pdftotext

```
text = textract.process('sample.pdf')
```

Error details as follows , giving full path aswell did not work

Executed in vscode windows 11

```
Exception has occurred: ShellError
The command `pdftotext sample.pdf -` failed with exit code 127
------------- stdout -------------
------------- stderr -------------
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "pdf_extract.py", line 8, in <module>
    text = textract.process('sample.pdf')
textract.exceptions.ShellError: The command `pdftotext sample.pdf -` failed with exit code 127
------------- stdout -------------
------------- stderr -------------
```

Comment: The error message is clear. Were you able to troubleshoot it?

Comment: no , there is file in the location. Still the error. not sure if this is related to windows not working with textract ?

Am i missing anything ?

Comment: are you in the right folder when the process in running? you can print it out using `import os \n cwd = os.getcwd()`